# Qualification Type Id for subdivison in Mechanical Turk in R

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

What will be Qualification Type ID for writing State name along with Country name:

```
  qualReqs = paste(
  # Set Location to US only
  GenerateQualificationRequirement(
    "Locale","==","US-NJ"),
  sep="" )
newHIT = CreateHIT(
  # layoutid in sandbox:
  hitlayoutid="XXX",
  annotation = "Survey23-Oct",
  assignments = "5",
  title="Survey-23-Oct",
  description="XXXX",
  reward=".10",
  duration=seconds(hours=4),
  expiration=seconds(days=7),
  keywords="XXXX",
  auto.approval.delay=seconds(days=15),
  qual.req=qualReqs
)
```

## This is the code i m using where i m getting the  error.

Error (AWS.InvalidEnumeratedParameter): The value "US-NJ" you specified for Locale ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 Country Codes is invalid. Expected values [AD, AE, AF, AG, AI, AL, AM, AN, AO, AQ, AR, AS, AT, AU, AW, AX, AZ, BA, BB, BD, BE, BF, BG, BH, BI, BJ, BM, BN, BO, BR, BS, BT, BV, BW, BY, BZ, CA, CC, CD, CF, CG, CH, CI, CK, CL, CM, CN, CO, CR, CS, CU, CV, CX, CY, CZ, DE, DJ, DK, DM, DO, DZ, EC, EE, EG, EH, ER, ES, ET, FI, FJ, FK, FM,

If I use Qualification Type ID: `00000000000000000071` then I can write Country name only. I also want to add State name in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have >= MTurkR v0.6.11, you can do this very easily:

```
GenerateQualificationRequirement("Locale","==","US-NJ")
```

This version is not yet on CRAN, so you will need to install from GitHub as of 26 October 2015:

```
library("devtools")
install_github("leeper/MTurkR")
```

Note that [there also appears to be a problem with the AWS API](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=218635) that will cause this to fail. If you receive an error such as:

> Error (AWS.MechanicalTurk.InvalidParameterValue): The value "2013-11-15 or earlier" is not valid for the parameter WSDL.version. Expected values 2013-11-15. You are attempting to use a feature that's unsupported in the WSDL version you've requested.  Please use the current WSDL version: 2013-11-15. (1445850568005 s)

Then pass an explicit `version` argument to the `CreateHIT()` function:

```
CreateHIT(your arguments, version = "2014-08-15")
```

until this is resolved.

Comment: Still getting the error:
Error (AWS.InvalidEnumeratedParameter): The value "US-NJ" you specified for Locale ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 Country Codes is invalid. Expected values [AD, AE, AF, AG, AI, AL, AM, AN, AO, AQ, AR, AS, AT, AU, AW, AX, AZ, BA, BB, BD, BE, BF, BG, BH, BI, BJ, BM, BN, BO, BR, BS, BT, BV, BW, BY, BZ, CA, CC, CD, CF, CG, CH, CI, CK, CL, CM, CN, CO, CR, CS, CU, CV, CX, CY, CZ, DE, DJ, DK, DM, DO, DZ, EC, EE, EG, EH, ER, ES, ET, FI, FJ, FK, FM, FO, FR, GA, GB, GD, G

Comment: @RickyBilakhia What version of MTurkR do you have? You can see this by typing `sessionInfo()` into your R console?

Comment: i have MTurkR_0.6.9 version installed

Comment: edited the actual post, so you can see the code and help me out.

Comment: @RickyBilakhia Thanks. This was a bug, which [I have now fixed](https://github.com/leeper/MTurkR/commit/8b73c9ba9069c170a2c54a861f899c34834af98c). Please see my edits to my answer.